# Why does Rambam count learning from Midos in 613 Mitzvos?

Tags: halacha-theory, rambam, mitzvah, arayot

This is a follow-up question to "[why-one's-daughter-is-not-mentioned-in-arayos-in-the-torah"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/why-ones-daughter-is-not-mentioned-in-arayos-in-the-torah) (please read before continuing).

Both the Gemmorah and Rambam agree that the prohibition of one's daughter comes from a Drashah (either Kal Vachomer or Gzerah Shavah).

In his Introduction ([Shoresh 2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.2?lang=bi)) Rambam specifies that:

> שאין ראוי למנות כל מה שלמדים באחת משלש עשרה מדות שהתורה נדרשת בהן או מרבוי:
>
> Do not include laws which are derived from one of the Thirteen Principles of Torah Exegesis (CHabad.org).

Those two look like a contradiction not only to me by to RambaN also.

Why does Rambam override his own rule especially in this prohibition?

Comment: Very good question. My Rosh Yeshiva gave a long Shiur on explaining Shoresh Beis last year; B”N I’ll dig up my notes and post as an answer later.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Rambam himself addresses this in shoresh sheni...

Comment: @robev you'd be very disappointed, instead RambaN attacks him on tens of examples (Isur Bas is just one of many).

Comment: ספר המצוות לרמב"ם שורש ב 
אבל אמנם יימנה מה שהיה פירוש מקובל ממנו והוא שיבארו המעתיקים ויאמרו שזה הדבר אסור לעשותו ואיסורו דאורייתא (על"ת קלה קצד קצט) **או יאמרו שהוא גוף תורה (על"ת שלו) הנה נמנה אותו כי הוא נודע בקבלה לא בהקש**. Looks like he addressed it to me.

Comment: @robev That's to be exact "כי הוא נודע בקבלה לא בהקש", however Ervas Bas is learned by either byקל וחומר or גזרה שווה.

Comment: I feel like you didn't read shoresh sheni. The words that immediately follow what I copied say " זכרון ההקש בו והביא הראיה עליו באחת משלש עשרה מדות להראות חכמת הכתוב"